# Swift set color of string in array

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uicolor

I am trying to create a app where you can browse through the weapon finishes in CS:GO.

```
    var uspGrades = ["Covert", "Classified", "Classified", "Classified", "Restricted", "Restricted", "Restricted", "Restricted", "Mil-Spec", "Mil-Spec", "Mil-Spec", "Mil-Spec", "Mil-Spec", "Mil-Spec", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial",]
```

This is the array which has the conditions of weapon finishes. All of this is now displayed in a Label in a TableViewCell.
So, this is my question. How can I change the colours of the strings in uspGrades?
e.g the first cell will display Covert, and that should be red, and the second cell will display Classified and that should be pink.

I apologize for my bad explanation, but hope somebody understand what i mean.

Comment: "the first cell will display Covert, and that should be red" It's easy to set the color of a label's text, so what's the hard part for you?

Comment: Sorry if I explained it wrong.
cell.collectionLabel.text = uspCollections[indexPath.row]
That is the code which load the Array into the Label. I want the label to change color based on the Strings in the Array. So "Covert" is red, "Classified" is pink etc

Comment: As you've been told in the answers, all you have to do is store the desired color _in_ `uspGrades`, each color along with its string. Then for each row you assign the string as the label's text and the color as its text color.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your array as an array of touples like this:

```
let uspGrades: [(name: String, color: UIColor)] = [("Covert", UIColor.redColor()), ("Classified", UIColor.blueColor())]
```

And after you can acces the string as `uspGrades[i].name` and color as `uspGrades[i].color`

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly! Not easy being new to programming!

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple struct to store string and color combinations. Something like:

```
struct Weapon {

     let name : String
     let color : UIColor

}
```

//declare your datasource variable

```
private var uspGrades : [Weapon]!
```

Then populate your datasource:

```
func populateDatasource {
    self.uspGrades = [Weapon]()

    self.uspGrades.append(Weapon("Covert", UIColor.redColor())
    self.uspGrades.append(Weapon("Classified", UIColor.pinkColor())
...
...

}
```

Finally, implement the UITableView datasource methods, and set the properties, for eg:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cCell")

     cell.textLabel.text = uspGrades[indexPath.row].name
     cell.textLabel.textColor = uspGrades[indexPath.row].color
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Tried that, but got an error "Use of unresolved identifier ´uspUpgrades´ on both the last lines?

Comment: You need to declare an instance variable with the same name. I have made the relevant edits.